# Search box title inconsistency

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, top-bar

The current background text in the top bar search box reads "search Q&A". When you click to enter content, but leave it empty and click outside, it reverts to "search".

[image]

Could this be reverted back to "search Q&A"?

Comment: oh wow. nice catch! .....quite the edge case!

Comment: [Does this make you nervous?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cMoFi.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good catch!

A fix is live now. Thanks for the report.

Comment: Not sure if bug or not, but when I type something then delete it, there's no placeholder text. Ordinary placeholder should stick in such cases, as far as I know. :)

Comment: I'm leaning more towards "search Q&A" rather than "Search Q&A" since it's close to other menu items that show an action via lowercase only... but that might only be personal preference.